# Greek month with no punctuation convert to Date using Date.ParseExact

Tags: c#, date, datetime-format

I have a Greek date `"08 Ιουνιου 2021"` which I want to convert to `Date`. This is not possible because the month is missing some punctuation. The correct month is `"Ιουνίου"` which actually works correctly via the code below

```
var greek = new CultureInfo("el-GR").DateTimeFormat;
var dtFormat = DateTime.ParseExact("08 Ιουνίου 2021", "dd' 'MMMM' 'yyyy", greek, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Any ideas how to get the month to be formatted correctly?

Comment: So, you only need this for Greek months an nothing else? As described in comments, this method can be applied to other languages/cultures, but without any guarantee of success. If it's just for Greek, I can post it as answer, sure.

Comment: @Jimi I do need it for Greek for now. I believe it would be a great contribution for the community if you post something more general when you have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to normalize the month name, using a diacritic insensitive comparison to retrieve the correct Month name from the [CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthgenitivenames) collection, since in some cultures the genitive name is different from the nominative (the date is presented in the form:  `8th of June, 2021`).

A [String.Compare()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare) overload accepts both CultureInfo and [CompareOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareoptions) arguments.
The **`IgnoreNonSpace`** flag: *Indicates that the string comparison must ignore nonspacing combining characters, such as diacritics. [...]*.
This allows to search for the month name, ignoring the missing diacritics, in the `MonthGenitiveNames` collections and return the corresponding, proper, name.

The *normalized* date can then be passed to [DateTime.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse), along with the provided CultureInfo, to extract the DateTime object.

Sample method call:

```
var normalizedDateTime = NormalizeMonthDiacritics(new CultureInfo("el-GR"), "08 Ιουνιου 2021");
```

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

internal DateTime NormalizeMonthDiacritics(CultureInfo culture, string date)
{
    string[] inputDateParts = date.Split();

    inputDateParts[1] = culture.DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames.FirstOrDefault(month => 
        string.Compare(inputDateParts[1], month, culture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) == 0) 
        ?? inputDateParts[1];

    string normalizedDate = string.Join(" ", inputDateParts);

    if (DateTime.TryParse(normalizedDate, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dtm)) {
        return dtm;
    }
    else {
        throw new ArgumentException("The provided date cannot be normalized", 
              new Exception("Month Genitive form not available"));
    }
}
```

---

Since at least 37 cultures use month names composed of 2 or more parts, to make the method more generic and also apply the same procedure to the [Abbreviated Month Genitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviatedmonthgenitivenames) names, this method could be modified to parse the input date in a slight different way and also allow to specify whether the month name is provided in short format.

The date format can be then composed of these 3 parts:

1. Numeric value representing either the Day of Month or the Year
2. Month part, Genitive Name, in either long format string (`MMMM`) or short format (`MMM`)
3. Numeric value representing either the Year or the Day of Month

`DateTime.TryParse()` can handle a DateTime format in both ways.

Call this modified method like this:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("sah-RU");
string date = "2020 атырдьах ыиын 08";  // <= Should be атырдьах ыйын
var normalizedDateTime = NormalizeMonthDiacritics(culture, date, false);
```

Modified method:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

internal DateTime NormalizeMonthDiacritics(CultureInfo culture, string date, bool monthShortForm = false)
{
    string pattern = @"(\d+)\s+(.*?)\s+(\d+)";
    var parts = Regex.Match(date, pattern, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Singleline)
                     .Groups.OfType<Capture>().Skip(1).Take(3).Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();

    var monthNames = monthShortForm 
                   ? culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames 
                   : culture.DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames;

    parts[1] = monthNames.FirstOrDefault(month =>
        string.Compare(parts[1], month, culture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) == 0)
        ?? parts[1];

    string normalizedDate = string.Join(" ", parts);

    if (DateTime.TryParse(normalizedDate, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dtm)) {
        return dtm;
    }
    else {
        throw new ArgumentException("The provided date cannnot be normalized",
              new Exception("Month Genitive form not available"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly the extension of the problem here - whether the values come from database or whether this is just a single occurrence or whether requires more than first established -

The idea is to create a mapping between the diacritics words( in this case months) and non diacritics.

When the date value `08 Ιουνιου 2021`is passed we check it against a mapping of months that contains the diacritics.

The comparison is done by

```
string.Compare(firstString, secondString, new CultureInfo("el-GR"), CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace);
```

From Msdn documentation - [IgnoreNonSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareoptions?view=netcore-3.1):

*Indicates that the string comparison must ignore nonspacing combining characters, such as diacritics. The Unicode Standard defines combining characters as characters that are combined with base characters to produce a new character. Nonspacing combining characters do not occupy a spacing position by themselves when rendered.*

This could/would be a potential fix:

```
    static string originalValue = "08 Ιουνιου 2021";
    static string[] currentMonth = originalValue.Split(' ');

    static List<string> monthMapping = new List<string>
        {
            //add others months mapping - I dont know how they are spelt -
            "Ιουνίου"
        };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTimeFormatInfo greek = new CultureInfo("el-GR").DateTimeFormat;

        foreach (string month in monthMapping)
        {
            if( string.Compare(currentMonth[1], month, new CultureInfo("el-GR") , CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) == 0)
            {
                var dtFormat = DateTime.ParseExact($"08 {month} 2021", "dd' 'MMMM' 'yyyy", greek, DateTimeStyles.None);
            }

        }
    }
```